# Extendscript in Indesign not creating or writing to file

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I am writing a script for Indesign that collects the contents from `TextStyleRange` objects, adds them to a javascript object, and should then write out a JSON file with the stringified JSON.

I can create the JSON just fine, with the contents from all of the `TextStyleRange`s in the current document, however the final file never gets written.

Here is a simplified example of what I have:

```js
#include "json2.js";
main();
function main(){
    myObj = { "key_1": "value_1", "key_2": "value_2" };
    myContents = JSON.stringify(myObj, null, 4);
    myFile = new File("~/Documents/myproject/en/translation.json");
    myFile.open("w");
    myFile.write( myContents );
    $.writeln( myContents );
    myFile.close();
}
```

In the VSCode debugger I can correctly see the JSON being output by `$.writeln`, however the file is not being created on disk. Any ideas what might be going wrong?

I'm using Windows 10, and Adobe Indesign 2022.

I have also tried with file edit but no luck:

```js
myFile.open("e", "????", "????");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it was simply that I needed to create the subfolder first:

```js
var parentFolder = myFile.parent;
if (!parentFolder.exists && !parentFolder.create())
    throw new Error("Cannot create file in path " + myFile.fsName);
```

After adding this to my script the folder and the file were created successfully.